# Assign Id and iterate through rows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-table, getelementbyid

I created a table, which seems to work fine, but I have problems assigning an id to this table, count how many rows it has, and assign each row an id. The debugger says:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

I couldn't figure out what I did wrong. Can someone please help? I commented my questions in the code below as well:

```
function populateTable(list){
    var tableContent = "<table>";   
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
          var record = list[i];
        tableContent += "<tr><td>" + record.Title + "</td></tr>\n";
    }   
tableContent += "</table>";
tableContent.id="orders";
var rows = document.getElementById("orders").rows.length;//why is this null? 
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = rows;   
   for (var i=0; i< rows; ++i){
           //how do I assign an id for the element here? 
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have newline in table? <tr> already does that for you.

Comment: You're also missing the ending bracket of the function.

Comment: Thanks. It was a copy paste error. I edited it in. also I guess you could do without the /n

Comment: `tableContent` is not an HTML Element, it's just a string. You need to parse it first before assigning it an id.

Comment: Thanks! could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: I tried `document.getElementsByTagName("table").id="ordertable";`, but that didnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="here"> </div> <!-- the table will be added in this div -->
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function populateTable(list){
    var tableContent = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        var record = list[i];
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(record.Title);
        cell.appendChild(textnode);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        tableContent.appendChild(row);
    }   
    tableContent.id="orders";
    document.getElementById("here").appendChild(tableContent);  // the table is added to the HTML div element
    var rows = document.getElementById("orders").rows;
    for (var i=0; i < rows.length; ++i){
        rows[i].id = "myId" + (i+1);  // this is how you assign IDs
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }

}

var persons = [{Title:"John"}, {Title:"Marry"}];
populateTable(persons);
```

Comment: Thank you! could you explain a bit more about what var persons = [{Title:"John"}, {Title:"Marry"}]; does?

Comment: From your code: you have a list of elements (`list`) and the `i`th element looks like `var record = list[i];` in this list. But then you call `record.Title` which means that every element from your list is an object that has a property called `Title`. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp for details. This is why I created an array of objects (`persons`) containing some objects that have the `Title` property. Of course, I can create `var books = [{Title:"val1", Author:"X"},{Title:"val2", Author:"Y"},{Title:"val3", Author:"Z"}]`, but it was just a minimal example having 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

It seems you don't know how to properly create a DOM from javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

## Old answer

This line:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("orders").rows.length;//why is this null?
```

Get elements from HTML document by id. And it looks like you have not added `tableContent` yet to the document.

Comment: could you elaborate on that? I added  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = tableContent; to display it before getElementById("orders") , but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user3735871 You did it after, and you did it with *rows*

Comment: no I mean I added in a new line `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = tableContent;` to the original code to test, but it didnt work

Comment: I edited the answer, check the document.createElement stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion (read the comments in the code):

```
// This will create a table element and return it

function createTable(list){
    var table = document.createElement('table'); // This is an actual html element
    table.id = 'orders'; // Since it's an html element, we can assign an id to it

    tableHtml = ''; // This empty string will hold the inner html of the table we just created
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        var record = list[i];

        // we can assign the id here instead of looping through the rows again
        tableHtml += '<tr id="row-' + i + '"><td>' + record.Title + '</td></tr>';
    }   
    table.innerHTML = tableHtml; // We insert the html into the table element and parse it

    var rows = table.rows.length; // We already have a reference to the table, so no need of getElementById

    alert('rows'); // rows holds the number of rows. You can do whatever you want with this var.

    return table; // return the table. We still need to insert it into the dom
}


// Create a new table and hold it in memory
var myTable = createTable([{Title:'One'}, {Title:'Two'}, {Title:'Three'}]);

// Inset the newly created table into the DOM
document.getElementById('parent-of-table').appendChild(myTable);
```

Hope this helps

This is already been answered, but here's my version without all the comments:

```
function createTable(list){
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.id = 'orders';
    tableHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        tableHtml += '<tr id="row-' + i + '"><td>' + list[i].Title + '</td></tr>';
    }   
    table.innerHTML = tableHtml;
    var rows = table.rows.length;
    alert('rows');
    return table;
}
```